# How to resolve tree conflicts through svn Eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, svn, plugins

I have installed svn plugin in my eclipse recently and i want to know the way to resolve tree conflicts of my project through it.

Waiting for your valuable reply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

well, you didn't mention your OS whether it is windows or linux.
anyway, if it is windows you can download plugin for resolving conflicts i.e. called "tortoise". With the help of this plugin you can directly resolve any type of conflicts whether it is text conflicts or tree conflicts. What you need to do do just right click on the file having conflict and there is so many options, just select your desired option and make necessary changes if required. That's it.

And if it is Linux then just open the conflict affected file in project explorer and right click on that, then compare that file with the same file in branch(i.e. that you want to merge into your local code). If there is any change it will open both the file to compare and edit if file is unchanged then it will display a popup that there is no difference.
after this step just right click on file again and this time select "resolve conflict" option. Your file will be updated and conflict will be resolved also.

i hope it will make some sense to solve your problem.

Thanks,

vikS

Comment: Hello Vikram, my OS is Linux and thanks for your reply. I will try to resolve in the way you said.

Answer (score 13):

Right click the project, choose `Team-> Show Tree Conflict -> Mark as Resolved`

Answer (score 0):

Also has the possibility that, the file that you are committing has been deleted from repository.