# Subversion Eclipse Subclipse "local missing, incoming edit upon merge"

Tags: eclipse, svn, merge, subclipse

I'm using Eclipse 4.4RC4 with Subclipse 1.10.5. I added small chnages in r1000 that I don't need anymore, so I asked Eclipse to revert all changes in r1000. This mostly worked, except that `FooBar.java` has since moved from `/path/old` to `/path/new`, so I can't commit and I get the following "SVN Tree Conflicts":

```
/path/old/FooBar.java local missing, incoming edit upon merge
```

I have two questions:

- Why didn't Subversion/Subclipse follow the move history and simply merge the changes in `FooBar.java` in its new location?
- What's the *correct* way to resolve this? I suppose I could revert the changes to the non-existing `FooBar.java` file in the "SVN Tree Conflicts" tab, but that would do away with the merge metadata, wouldn't it? Wouldn't that mess up future automated merges, as Subversion would think that this particular change from r1000 hasn't been merged, yet?

I realize that similar questions have been asked before on this forum, but I found none specific to Eclipse/Subclipse, and none seemed to provide a good solution in that context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that the Subclipse "SVN Tree Conflicts" tab (**Team|Show Tree Conflict** as [others have noted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15808284/421049)) offers a **Resolve...** option in the main context menu of that tab (not in the Team context menu). Clicking on it brought up a resolve dialog that allowed me to choose the new destination of `FooBar.jar` so that the merge could continue and be applied to the correct file. Very cool! The merge succeeded, the correct destination file was modified, and I was allowed to perform the commit.